# why swing creators created mouseDragged method?

Tags: java, swing, mousemotionlistener

I always thought that difference between mouseMoved and mouseDragged is that you could get the button pressed in the mouseDragged event. Apparently, you can't, as I just found out. So what is the reason including/using mouseDragged method? Because as for now all my code looks like this:

```
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

            mouseMoved(e);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mouseMoved()` method is called when the user moves the mouse with no buttons pressed. The `mouseDragged()` method on the other hand is called when the user moves the mouse while holding down a mouse button.

Check out [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) for more information.

Comment: I'm not questioning how to use it. I'm questioning what were the reasons behind _the decision by swing developers_ to make 2 methods that do essentially the same. As for what I mean, is you probably 90% of time want to know which button was down when mouseDragged occurred, and you still have to create some booleans like leftPressed etc which are changed in MouseListener.

Comment: @user3787777 They're not essentially the same. That's your faulty assumption.